# Soliciting analogies for arguments to "["

Tags: r, extract

I have come around to thinking of arguments to "`[`" as being similar to machine gun belts:

```
set.seed(10)
datfrm <- data.frame(a= rev(letters[1:10]), b = runif(10), cc = letters[1:10] )
datfrm[datfrm$b < 0.5, "b"] <- 0
```

so the machine gun belt is only running through the first argument to "`[`":

```
               ---
               ---
               ---
               ---
datfrm[datfrm$b < 0.5, "b"] <- 0
```

But if you want to only make assignments to a subset,  say from another column:

```
               ---                         ---
               ---                         ---
               ---                         ---
               ---                         ---
datfrm[ datfrm$b < .5, "cc"] <- datfrm[ datfrm$b < .5, "a"]
```

The expression `datfrm$b` gets repeatedly evaluated and when they are paired on either side of an assignment... all proceeds as expected. So what's wrong or right with this and can it be improved?

Comment: not sure what you meant with that first line of code, but there were a lot of typos - can you check it now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the index first so it's only calculated once:

```
idx <- datfrm$b < .5
datfrm[idx, "cc"] <- datfrm[idx, "a"]
```

This is simpler to read and less prone to mistakes when making changes.

I think `within` probably provides the least typing, so using `idx` as above, and replacing the original with the output of within():

```
datfrm <- within(datfrm, cc[idx] <- a[idx])
```

Comment: Within provides the method that uses the least amount of typing - it's definitely not the cleanest! (because of the environment munging it does)